# How to display only custom contents contents in workspace rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Hi im building an RCP application based application in which i have a `Treeviewer` which will display my custom projects.For example i should be able to travese my file system and display only as eclipse does

```
c:\Eclipse\RCP\Workspace\(root directory)
       Project\(folder)
         class\(subfolder)
            .app
```

Till now i am possible to create

```
c:(all subfiles and subfolders)
 d:((all subfiles and subfolders)
 e:(all subfiles and subfolders)
 f:((all subfiles and subfolders)
```

Please let me know of some Sites/Books to help start me kick off programming in RCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas to look for:

- Add the Eclipse file system API (defined org.eclipse.core.resources), and then you can use the IWorkspace interface to access the file system, and display that in your Tree Viewer. If you are using the Common Navigator Framework ([a tutorial for that starts in the following post](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-1-what-im-going-to-do/)), it has built-in support for that.
- You can manually select the workspace folder, and use your existing content provider created for the TreeViewer, and start it from the workspace folder instead of the file system root.

For documentation you can look at the [tutorials at vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html) or the sometimes not too up-to-date [Eclipse Resources](http://eclipse.org/resources/).